# permutation with restriction - no two zeroes can be together from an set consisting of 3 or more zeroes

Tags: permutation, combinatorics

I have this as data set - `0 1 0 1 0` now how to find out the number of permutations with restriction that no two zeroes can be together.
i.e. 00110, 00011, 11000 etc. -> all of these are false cases

I was trying with `5!/2!.3! - (cases where two zeroes are always together)`.

But I am not able to find out how to do this. Any help ?

Comment: Are you asking for this particular data set or general problem with n zeros and m ones? In this data set, there is only one arrangement, one you stated.

Comment: @Ante yeah there is only one arrangement for the above case - though I am looking for an generic formula, but if provided for this case also that will help me to move further

Answer (score 0):

Lets have n 0's and m 1's. One or more 1's are placed between two 0's. Like 011101101...
There are 4 types of arrangements:

```
starts and ends with 0:    01101110
starts with 0 ends with 1: 011011101
starts with 1 ends with 0: 1101101110
starts and ends with 0:    1011011101
```

In first case there are n-1 groups of 1's, in second and third there are n groups, and in last case there are n+1 groups. So, result is:

```
A(m,n-1) + 2*A(m,n) + A(m,n+1),
```

where A(i,j) is a number of ways how to arrange i objects in j groups, so that each group have at least one element. With some calculations, it is shown that A(i,j) = C(i-1,j-1), where C is binomial coefficient.